# Number of integer vectors satisfying the constraint $\left|\mathbf{v}\right| \leq n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider a vector $\mathbf{v} = (v_1,\dots,v_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, i.e., a vector of $d$ components where each component is an integer. The norm (length) of $\mathbf{v}$ is given by

$$
\left|\mathbf{v}\right|=\sqrt{v_{1}^{2}+\dots+v_{d}^{2}}.
$$

I was curious to find either an exact expression or an estimate for the number of possible vectors $\mathbf{v}$ that satisfy the criterion $\left|\mathbf{v}\right| \leq n$, where $n$ is a positive **integer**.

For $n=1$ this is simple, because in this case only one component of $\mathbf{v}$ can be nonzero (i.e., $v_i=\pm 1$ for some $i$ and zero otherwise), which means that there are $2d + 1$ options (the factor $2$ is due to the two possible signs, and the plus one is due to $\mathbf{v}=0$, which trivially satisfies the criterion). However, already for $n=2$ this becomes slightly complicated, because the possibilities range from having no nonzero components to having $4$ non-zero components that can be located at different indices and have different signs. What is the simplest way of calculating the possibilities for a general $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as finding the number of points with integer coordinates which lie in the sphere of radius $n$ in $\mathbb R^d$, centered at the origin. If we put a unit $d$-dimensional cube centered at each such point, then the union of these cubes will have a volume which is approximately equal to the volume of the unit sphere. Therefore, a pretty good estimate for the number of points is just the volume of the sphere of radius $n$ in $\mathbb R^d$, which is $$\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2+1)}\cdot n^d.$$